# DOM xpath breaks quotation marks

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to parse some UTF-8 encoded html text that contains the left and right quotation marks ’
But when I try to get the value of the html back from DOM with saveHTML(), the quotation marks always get messed up.

Now I've tried several including utf8_encoding the text before putting it into DOM, I've tried putting ('1.0', 'UTF-8') into the constructor and it also didn't work.

I'm running out of ideas how to sort this out. 
Converting the quotation marks into html entities isn't the option for me.

Here is a simplified example that breaks the quotation marks:

```
$a = "<html><body><div>won’t you, will you, won’t you, join the </div></body></html>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($a);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tag = $xpath->query('//div');

foreach($tag as $t)
    echo $dom->saveHTML($t);
```

the returned text looks like: will you,  wonât you, will you, wonât you, join the

Comment: Do you know what charset your string is in? I bet it's not utf8

Comment: it's utf8. However, like I said in the question. If I use the utf8_encode on the string and then pass it to dom, I get the same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you insist on using loadHTML then try this:

add an appropriate meta tag to your html first, like this:

```
$a = "<html>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
<body><div>won’t you, will you, won’t you, join the </div></body></html>";
```

Then you can use loadHTML($a) and it will work

Lastly, you you just cannot add the extra meta tag then you can try this:
use $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($a) );
this will work too as it will first convert your string to latin-1 from utf8 which will then be loaded into dom in latin-1 charset and you will get output as latin-1 also.

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to use $dom->loadXML($a) instead of loadHTML()
I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: The reason is that loadXML will always use utf-8 while loadHTML will use latin-1 as default charset unless charset is given in the meta tag of html markup

Comment: hmm... if I change the loadHMTL to loadXML I get back the string with the xml entities of the quotation marks like this: "ill you,  won&#xE2;&#x80;&#x99;t you, will you,"
It doens't do it for me